# Push a multidimensional array in Jquery

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, push

I have an array set to "values", and within the array is an multidimensional array called items.

```
values = {
         full_name: fullname,
         items: [{'item-id': '001', 'item-special': 'nothing'}, {'item-id': '031', 'item-special': 'Make it blue'}],
         address_full: address
         };
```

How would I push more items into the array?

```
{'item-id': '055', 'item-special': 'Extra large'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
values.items.push({'item-id': '055', 'item-special': 'Extra large'});
```

should work :)