# how to break array into chunks and post them to mysql?

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have got value using

```
var data = [];

  $('#customers > tbody  > tr').each(function(){


    var rollno=$(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    var marks=$(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').find('input').val();


      if(marks=='' ||subjcode=='')
     {
         alert('marks is null')
     }
     else
     {
         data.push(rollno);
         data.push(subjcode);
         data.push(marks);
         //data.push(teacherid);
     }

  })//each
```

actually I got an array containing several values but I want to break them int chunks of 3 and post them into database....what to do?

can I post them using foreach ??
if yes then how?
if no then what are the other methods?

Comment: Can you please be more accurate on what you want to do ?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365100/push-a-multidimensional-array-in-jquery) may help you

Comment: `$.ajax`, `$.post` and `array_chunk` spring to mind, they're pretty descriptive function names IMO

Comment: Don't push the values into an array - just post them in groups of 3 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$("#customers > tbody  > tr").each(function(){
    var rollno = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    var subjcode $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
    var marks = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").find("input").val();

    if (marks == "" || subjcode == "") {
        console.log("marks is null")
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "your-data-handler.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                rollno: rollno,
                subjcode: subjcode,
                marks: marks
            },
            success: function() {
                // success handler
            },
            error: function() {
                // error handler
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've guessed at the value for `subjcode`, but it's an example of pushing the data to a php file that could handle it and save it to a database.

I really would recommend sending all the data at once though.  Many requests will have a lot of overheads and slow down both the process for the user and your web server.